# Isolate constant in sum with floor function

Tags: summation

This is not the whole problem but I'm stuck here, I dont know if this is even possible.

Having this formula:

$$
\huge\sum_{t=0}^{n}{k_{t}(-1)^{\left \lfloor{\frac{b}{2^{t}}}\right \rfloor }}
$$

Where $k_{t}$ is a value for each $t$ and $\left \lfloor{\frac{b}{2^{t}}}\right \rfloor $ is the floor function for $\frac{b}{2^{t}}$

Where $b$ is a **natural number** and the **constant** I want to isolate it must also be in the range $0\leqslant b < 2^{n}$. Im expecting something like:

$$
\huge f(b)\sum_{t=0}^{n}{g(t)}
$$

In this case a product, but it may be also a sum (?).

I also know that for each $t$ the formula is adding a function $f(t,b)$ with this form:

$$
t=0\\
f(0,0) = +1\\
f(0,1) = -1\\
f(0,2) = +1\\
f(0,3) = -1\\
...\\
t=1\\
f(1,0) = +1\\
f(1,1) = +1\\
f(1,2) = -1\\
f(1,3) = -1\\
f(1,4) = +1\\
f(1,5) = +1\\
f(1,6) = -1\\
f(1,7) = -1\\
...\\
t=2\\
f(2,0) = +1\\
f(2,1) = +1\\
f(2,2) = +1\\
f(2,3) = +1\\
f(2,4) = -1\\
f(2,5) = -1\\
f(2,6) = -1\\
f(2,7) = -1\\
...\\
$$

I tried to write the floor function with a sum of sigmoids as:

$$
\huge F(x) = \left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor  = \sum_{s=0}^{s_{max}}{\frac{1}{1+e^{2p(s-x)}}}
$$

Where a bigger $p$ means a better accuracy and the ideal function when $p\rightarrow\infty$. Now the original sum will be this one:

$$
\huge \sum_{t=0}^{n}{k_{t}(-1)^{F(\frac{b}{2^{t}})}}
$$

Is this possible ? I probably dont know the methods to resolve this (if they exists). I will be grateful with a detail explanation or a link or name of the process.

Thanks

Comment: Ugh, please don't make your formulae such super size.

Comment: I thought they where too small to see the little fractions, should I just let them that way ?

Comment: Let it ride for now. Just be aware for future posts. If size becomes an issue, then scaling up one notch is ok. For the last formula, I would rewrite it in two pieces "$\sum xx(xx)^y$ where $y = \sum zz$"

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think the last one is cleaner now :)

Comment: Are you signaling for help to aliens from outer space ? :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian Nice one !

Answer (score 0):

Since $b$ is a constant integer and you know that it is $0 \le b < n$, 
then express it in binary
$$
b = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {d_{\,k} 2^{\,k} } \quad \left| {\;d_{\,k}  = 0,1} \right.
$$

Now the floor reduces to
$$
\left\lfloor {{b \over {2^{\,t} }}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {d_{\,k} 2^{\,k - t} } } \right\rfloor
  = \sum\limits_{t\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {d_{\,k} 2^{\,k - t} } 
$$
and clearly
$$
\left\lfloor {{b \over {2^{\,t} }}} \right\rfloor \bmod 2 = d_{\,t} 
$$
which means
$$
\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,\left\lfloor {{b \over {2^{\,t} }}} \right\rfloor }  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,d_{\,t} }  = \left\{ {\matrix{
   1 & {\left| {\,d_{\,t}  = 0} \right.}  \cr 
   { - 1} & {\left| {\,d_{\,t}  = 1} \right.}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$

Thus your sum splits into two simple ones, according to the binary representation of $b$.